# Lotus flower encryption

Tags: cipher

Decrypting this single word below, may enhance your overall health and well being.

The best answer will include an explanation of the encryption step**s**.
<sub>(An understanding of color models may be helpful.)</sub>

[image: Lotus]

Comment: My first try came up with `ARTZ3`. I assume that's not close?

Comment: Solving this puzzle is perhaps an EXERCISE.

Comment: I assume you already know the answer, Aravind?

Comment: No, just guessed an 8-letter word that enhances health and well-being :)

Comment: I don't think the word is 8 letters, personally.

Comment: There seems to be some varing number of transparent pixels rows between the lotus flowers. Is this information needed for decryption, or just an side-effect of creating this image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> MEDITATE 
>
> CMYK - RGB colour codes 
> blac**K C**yan **B**lue **G**reen **R**ed **Y**ellow **R**ed **C**yan 
>
>
> KCBGRYRC + Caesar Cipher = MEDITATE

Comment: Good one, but why you take the last letter of Black while you consider only the first letter of the other words? Is there a reason or just to make it fit?

Comment: In printing and graphical software:- Historically the K is always used for Black as B is used for Blue - so not to cause confusion. Usage: CMYK for Print - RGB for on screen graphic work

Comment: How restrictive was the choice of puzzle answer given that seven fixed letters had to Caesar shift to it?

Comment: @xnor - If I understand your question, I had to go back and forth between anagramming and Caesar shifting multiple times before I found a word that used most of the letters.

Answer (score 3):

Thoughts toward a solution:

---

Assuming the colours follow an RGB scheme, they are combinations of the elementary colours of light: red, green, and blue. If we convert the presence of a colour to `1` and its absence to `0`, we get the following binary code from the digits:

```
000 011 001 010 100 110 100 011
```

I've been playing with different ways of encoding these numbers, with no luck:

```
0000 1100 1010 1001 1010 0011 - 0ca9a3 in hexadecimal, doesn't mean anything
00001 10010 10100 11010 0011 - 5 doesn't go evenly into 24
000011 001010 100110 100011 - CJpm in base64, doesn't mean anything
00001100 10101001 10100011 - doesn't mean anything in ASCII or Unicode
```

If we assume instead that they're in a CMY configuration, then the binary code is inverted:

```
111 100 110 101 011 001 011 100
```

And if we try the groupings above:

```
1111 0011 0101 0110 0101 1100 - f3563c in hexadecimal, doesn't mean anything
11110 01101 01011 00101 1100 - 5 doesn't go evenly into 24
111100 110101 011001 011100 - 81Zc in base64, doesn't mean anything
11110011 01010110 01011100 - doesn't mean anything in ASCII or Unicode
```

Comment: I've been trying the same things :-)

Comment: Great programmers think alike. :P

Comment: Given the hint, what about a CMYK scheme?

Comment: The CMYK encoding is 0001 1000 1101 1011 0111 0010 0111 1000.

Comment: Wait, how do any of the lotuses except the first one have any K?

Comment: It looks like your CMYK encoding is the same as the CMY one, but with one bit that enforces an odd parity.

Comment: Except that a black lotus is `0001` since none of the CMY are used.

Comment: Also, with the "s" in steps being bolded, I can't help but think that there's more to it than just this.

Comment: Assuming one symbol maps to one letter and the same color is the same letter, performing a dictionary attack gives `levitate` and `meditate` as two striking possibilities for a solution (along with others such as `hesitate` and `tricolor`). But I can't find any way to correlate these possible solutions to the colors in a way that makes sense.

Comment: I assume it's `meditate`, then, given the "overall health and well-being" clue. Maybe it maps in another language?

Comment: We don't know what letters magenta or white would have mapped to.

Comment: I tried Braille (four 3*2 blocks), but didn't get anything valid. Another thought is that it's a melody that we recognize from the notes, but 0-indexed letters ADBCEGDC don't seem to give one.